# Using Twitter API in R

Tags: r, twitter-r

I am using the twitter api in R and trying to perform some analysis. I have a set of zip codes(lat/long) and I want to fetch all the twitter handles for a particular zip code. Is that possible? Need help on that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the twitter API, but there is an R package built to interface with it called twitteR. It might be able to help. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf

Comment: #1 No, faik it's not possible using the standard twitter api (check out its documentation). #2 Also check out https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/index.html as an alternative to the deprecated twitteR package.

Comment: Yeah, I felt the same that it is not possible. Is there a way to find that out using any language, not specifically R? Or will there be privacy issues involved?